# Problem with SQL statement using group by and restricting to distinct values

Tags: sql

I have a question on SQL, my Query results should be like

table having duplicate party_id, each of party_id can have diff types of iden_typ
is it possible to write SQL query to result

different party-ids having unique iden_typs
so far I am able to identify duplicate party_id but not able to restrict distinct iden-types with in party id
My query is some thing like:

```
select party_id, iden-_type from 
  tableA group by party_id, iden_typ 
having count(party_id) > 1 and count(distinct iden_typ) > 1
where partition_date='20200307' and iden_typ in ('FRN','DRN','CRN','OTH')
```

Comment: Sample and desired results would really help.

Comment: tableA is having duplicate party_ids and each of party_id can have diff types of iden-types (there are 17 iden types) but for processing we are considering party_id with 4 specific iden_typ ('FRN',''CRN','DRN','OTH)  I am able to find party_id having same kind of iden_typ but party_id with distinct iden-typ would be needed for processing     Trying to find distinct values with in sub group

Answer (score 0):

`Where` should go before aggregation :

```
select party_id, iden-_type 
from tableA 
where partition_date='20200307' and iden_typ in ('FRN','DRN','CRN','OTH')
group by party_id, iden_typ 
having count(party_id) > 1 and count(distinct iden_typ) > 1;
```

If you want  `party_id` which is having a duplicate `iden_typ` then you can do :

```
select party_id, iden-_type 
from tableA 
where partition_date='20200307' and iden_typ in ('FRN','DRN','CRN','OTH')
group by party_id, iden_typ 
having count(distinct iden_typ) > 1;
```

If you want full rows then you can use `exists` :

```
select ta.*
from tableA ta
where partition_date='20200307' and iden_typ in ('FRN','DRN','CRN','OTH') and
      exists (select 1 
              from tableA taa 
              where taa.party_id = ta.party_id and 
                    taa.iden_typ <> ta.iden_typ
             );
```